# pop up window creation in wxpython

Tags: python, popup, wxpython, frames

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# myconfig.py

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.cfg = wx.Config('myconfig')
        if self.cfg.Exists('width'):
            w, h = self.cfg.ReadInt('width'), self.cfg.ReadInt('height')
        else:
            (w, h) = (250, 250)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(w, h))

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Width:', (20, 20))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Height:', (20, 70))
        self.sc1 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, str(w), (80, 15), (60, -1), min=200, max=500)
        self.sc2 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, str(h), (80, 65), (60, -1), min=200, max=500)
        wx.Button(self, 1, 'Save', (20, 120))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave, id=1)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.Centre()

    def OnSave(self, event):
        self.cfg.WriteInt("width", self.sc1.GetValue())
        self.cfg.WriteInt("height", self.sc2.GetValue())
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Configuration saved, %s ' % wx.Now())


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'myconfig.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

how to popup a window if user hits more than max or min value?

Comment: Please help to create a Pop up window,which is nessacaery for my real project work.

Comment: Are you asking some one to write it for you or is it just not working? If the latter show us the code we can then try to help..

Comment: actualy i am trying to run example code ,but in that i am not able to bring up pop up window if anybody put negative  value, so i asked experts(you people) to help me how to do that I mean write sample code for me please.

Comment: This isn't the place to get code written for you. Rather it is to help when your attempt is not working - we can find the mistakes.

Comment: Edit your question with whatever you tried that didn't work (especially if you got any errors).

Comment: I want to add my code and explain properly what i want to tell, but its nt allowing me to put my code here in coment

Comment: No edit it in the question not the comment section. Click `edit` underneath the question and paste the code :)

Comment: i have added code which i was trying,in that it wont accepts more than max value if we put, but i want instead of that to popup a window saying "entered value is not within the limit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `wx.MessageDialog`, `wx.MessageBox` or the more improved or `wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog.GenericMessageDialog`.

Comment: But how it will call the spinctrltext lib??

Comment: you will need to subclass it

Comment: How to do subclass inside the class? Will it required to call within the frame or need to create one more? any useful links?